# how to get current logged user id in community builder pro

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

i want to get current logged users id inside community builder pro  plugin i used this code but it did't work for me

```
   $user=&JFactory::getUser();
   $user->id;
```

Comment: If you `echo` that in a plug-in I'm not sure you would see anything in your output... where excactly was it? Did you have debug enabled and error messages turned up to "Development"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. It's an alternative method.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->get( 'id' );
```

[Read more.](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)

Comment: let me know if you have any issues :-)